# SvelteKit: +page.js load() function causes "500 Internal Error" after refreshing the page

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to use the load() function in the +page.js file to fetch data, which works fine after the initial load of the page. Though if I refresh the page (or change the code and it auto-refreshes) it gives me an error: "500 Internal Error".

I can navigate to another route on my page and go back to this page and it works again.

+page.js:

```
export async function load() {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    const books = await res.json();

    return {
        books
    }
}
```

+page.svelte:

```
<script>
    export let data
    let id = parseInt(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('id')) - 1
</script>

<h2>{data.books[id].title}</h2>
<p>{data.books[id].body}</p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling window before initialization, this code is evaluated server-side, in a context where it does not exist.
Import `browser` helper utility from sveltekit to deal with this, like so:

```js
import { browser } from '$app/environment';
export let data;
let id = 0;
             
if (browser)
  id = parseInt(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('id')) - 1
```